# Scoring matches of a game - reducing duplicated code

Tags: c++, gui, qt

I'm writing a small application to score matches of [a game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Tech_Challenge). (There are two "teams" on each "alliance", and two alliances play each other in a match.) I have  a "logic" class that handles the values of different scoring elements for each team, and calculates that team's score.

Instead of writing getters and setters for each member of the "logic" class, the `UI` class is a friend of the `logic` class and can access the `private` "scoring element" members of that class. Whenever a user enters something into the UI, the UI sets the "scoring element" member of that class--but it will pick a different "alliance" and "team" depending on which control was changed. This leads to a lot of code duplication that I want to avoid.

Here is an example:

```
void BlockParty::on_comboBox_red_A_currentIndexChanged(int index)
{
    switch (index) {
        case 0 :
            score_red->ramp_position_A = BlockPartyLogic::RAMP_OFF;
            break;
        case 1 :
            score_red->ramp_position_A = BlockPartyLogic::RAMP_PARTIAL;
            break;
        case 2 :
            score_red->ramp_position_A = BlockPartyLogic::RAMP_COMPLETE;
            break;
    }
    score_red->update_internals();
}
```

(`ramp_position_A` is an example of a "scoring element".) The above function needs to be repeated three more times, as `on_comboBox_red_B_currentIndexChanged`, `on_comboBox_blue_A`, and `on_comboBox_blue_B`.

Is there a good way to consolidate the logic into a single function that can call each slot with different parameters?

For example, something like the following:

```
void BlockParty::on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged(int index, Score* score)
{
    switch (index) {
        case 0 :
            score->ramp_position_A = BlockPartyLogic::RAMP_OFF;
            break;
        case 1 :
            score->ramp_position_A = BlockPartyLogic::RAMP_PARTIAL;
            break;
        case 2 :
            score->ramp_position_A = BlockPartyLogic::RAMP_COMPLETE;
            break;
    }
    score->update_internals();
}
```

I could make a giant `switch` statement to take care of the logic, but that doesn't actually address the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could put the statuses into a constant array and use the index variable to fetch them out:

```
void BlockParty::on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged(int index, Score* score)
{
  static const BlockPartyLogic value_table[] =
  {
    BlockPartyLogic::RAMP_OFF,      // Index 0
    BlockPartyLogic::RAMP_PARTIAL,  // Index 1
    BlockPartyLogic::RAMP_COMPLETE, // Index 2
  };
  if (index < sizeof(value_table) / sizeof(value_table[0]))
  {
    score->ramp_position_A = value_table[index];
  }
    score->update_internals();
}
```

If you want to *select functionality based on an index* you could use a `static` `const` array of function pointers or function objects.

Comment: Or `std::vector` (assuming no C++11 here), also allowing the first `if` to just use `size()`.

Comment: The problem is that an `std::vector` needs to be initialized at runtime.  The array is constant data and can be stored in read only memory and directly accessed.  No third-party structures need initializing.

Comment: That is true, and C++11 would make it nicer with `std::array`.  Still, this looks better than the `switch`.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to say from such a small view into your code, but generally, yes, you'll want to reduce the duplication in C++ code.

In particular in this case, if you have multiple teams which *all* have common logic, then that's probably best expressed using an array of identical classes.

```
class Team { ... };
std::vector<Team> team;
team.emplace_back(Team("red"));
team.emplace_back(Team("blue"));
team.emplace_back(Team("green"));
```

If you have a number of teams which all have *almost* the same logic, then there may be a clue that you'd benefit from subclasses.

```
class Baseteam { ... };
class RedTeam : public Baseteam { ... };
class BlueTeam : public Baseteam { ... };
class GreenTeam : public Baseteam { ... };
std::vector<Baseteam> team;
team.emplace_back(RedTeam());
team.emplace_back(BlueTeam());
team.emplace_back(GreenTeam());
```

If your intent instead is to reduce the `case` logic, you could either use an array (with bounds checking, of course) to select logic, or you could use polymorphism.  For the former, to rewrite your existing routine, it might be done something like this:

```
void BlockParty::on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged(int index, Score* score)
{
    static constexpr RAMPVALS = 3;
    static const auto ramp[RAMPVALS] { 
        BlockPartyLogic::RAMP_OFF, 
        BlockPartyLogic::RAMP_PARTIAL, 
        BlockPartyLogic::RAMP_COMPLETE
    };
    if (index < 0 || index > RAMPVALS)
        index = 0;
    score->ramp_position_A = ramp[index];
    score->update_internals();
}
```

The problem with this is that it brings `BlockPartyLogic` items into `BlockParty`.  Better would be to push that into `BlockPartyLogic` instead:

```
void BlockParty::on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged(int index, Score* score)
{
    score->ramp_position_A = BlockPartyLogic::RampVal(index);
    score->update_internals();
}
```